# how can i get a value from an ajax function to execute another one

Tags: jquery, getjson

I been looking and reading for about 3 hours but i cant make it work. I want to get a value  from a function so i can use it to excute another function. I read that I have to create a callback but I'm new on this so i dont have much idea how to do it. Can you guys help me?

This is the code that pulls data from php:

```
                $.getJSON(callback_url, {
                ajax_action: 'list', 
                ajax_data: ''
            },   function(data){

            document.getElementById('ajax-box').innerHTML = "";

            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                document.getElementById('ajax-box').innerHTML += '<div> Some data loaded here</div>';

            }
            });
```

After this code I want to execute a new function if data length is more than "1" like this:

```
 if (data.length > 1) { some function here}
```

I get an error :

> ReferenceError: data is not defined
>     if (data.length > 1) {

Regards,

Comment: Can you confirm that `data` is actually a JSON array? Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` and see what that says.

Comment: I assume you know you can call another function from inside the function(data) block? Just do a conditional check there, and call whatever function you want.

Comment: @AlexReidy Thanks a lot ... I forgot that!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error since scope of `data` is not outside the `ajax call`.

Keep a variable outside the ajax call and use that to access the data

```
var d;
                $.getJSON(callback_url, {
                ajax_action: 'list', 
                ajax_data: ''
            },   function(data){
            d = data; // added in your code
            document.getElementById('ajax-box').innerHTML = "";

            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                document.getElementById('ajax-box').innerHTML += '<div> Some data loaded here</div>';

            }
            }); 
// use your d here
```

Also I would strongly suggest you to write better code when using jQuery, user $("#") instead of getElementById etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doAjax(postUrl,postBody,callback){
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: postUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(postBody),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
        callback(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           callback(thrownError);
        }
     });
}
doAjax(callback_url,{request_body_json},function(data){
       document.getElementById('ajax-box').innerHTML = "";
       for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
         document.getElementById('ajax-box').innerHTML += '<div> Some data loaded here</div>';
    }
});
```

This way is best for you, just use the doAjax method  and handle your code.